# pass two variables to main content

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to pass two variables to a page and i'm not sure would i do it.
I need to tell it to load a specific view and also pass sql results to this view.

```
// template.php

<?php
$this->load->view('includes/header');
$this->load->view($main_content);
$this->load->view('includes/footer');
?>


// my controller
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MyController extends CI_Controller {

    function query()
    {
        $this->load->model('search');

        $data['main_content'] = 'query_results';
        $sql['rows'] = $this->search->getAll();

        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data, $sql); // no clue how to pass $sql to the view

    }
}
?>
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: Avoid closing PHP tags (?>), as you have here. Might produce unwanted results. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You should change your function to

```
function query()
{
    $this->load->model('search');

    $data['main_content'] = 'query_results';
    $data['rows'] = $this->search->getAll();

    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);

}
```

Now you can access your results in the view via the variable `$rows`.

You can find the reference [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html), section "Adding Dynamic Data".

Comment: thank you very much. that was very dumb of me. it was much easier than i though

Comment: Glad I could help, please mark the post as the answer by clicking on the checkmark on the left of the post ;)